# beamer bullet outside itemize with different colour

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm trying to define a new item, it is exactly the same of the beamer bullet point but I want to change the colour, ho can I do?

This is the code, is there anyway to make the two colours of the pullet point equal?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysphere{%
\parbox[t]{10pt}{\raisebox{0.2pt}{\beamer@usesphere{item projected}{bigsphere}}}}
\makeatother

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=teal}

\title{test}


\author{}


\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ test}

\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}

\mysphere
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

is it possible to have the same colour for the two bullet points?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first argument for `\beamer@usesphere` sets the color used in the shading of the spheres. I'd suggest you to install a color using the settings for your `itemize item` template:

```
\setbeamercolor{mybullet}{use=itemize item.fg,bg=itemize item.fg,fg=itemize item.fg}
```

and then use this color in your definition

```
\beamer@usesphere{mybullet}{bigsphere}
```

In this way, if you eventually decide to change the `itemize item` color, your sphere will automatically inherit the change. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=teal}
\setbeamercolor{mybullet}{use=itemize item.fg,bg=itemize item.fg,fg=itemize item.fg}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mysphere{%
\parbox[t]{10pt}{\raisebox{0.2pt}{\beamer@usesphere{mybullet}{bigsphere}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ test}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\mysphere
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have a teal bullet? then your answer is to add the command `\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=teal}`.
This is the result:
[image]